# Gatsby: "document" is not available during server side rendering when building project using Bootstrap components with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, gatsby

I have a Gatsby project that uses Bootstrap (not React-Bootstrap, just Bootstrap). I want to use some Bootstrap components with JavaScript, but I get the error `"document" is not available during server side rendering` when building the project.

For instance, I have the following component `CollapseExample` that just has an [example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/#example) from Bootstrap docs. It doesn't do anything yet because there is no JavaScript from Bootstrap.

```js
// src/components/collapseexample.jsx
import * as React from "react";

export default function CollapseExample() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <a
        className="btn btn-primary"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        href="#collapseExample"
        role="button"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-controls="collapseExample"
      >
        Link with href
      </a>
      <div className="collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <div className="card card-body">
          Some placeholder content for the collapse component. This panel is
          hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant
          trigger.
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

And I have an index page with only an instance of `CollapseExample` like this:

```js
// src/pages/index.Jsx
import * as React from "react";
import CollapseExample from "../components/collapseexample.tsx";

export default function IndexPage () {
  return <CollapseExample />;
};
```

What I did is to import `Collapse` from Bootstrap and added a `Collapse` to the state of the `CollapseExample` componente, and then initialized it in a `useEffect` hook, like this:

```js
// src/components/collapseexample.jsx
import * as React from "react";
import { Collapse } from "bootstrap";

export default function CollapseExample() {
  /* Add Collapse component to state */
  const [collapse, setCollapse] = React.useState<Collapse>(null);

  /* Initialize Collapse component */
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (collapse === null) {
      const collapseElement = document.getElementById("collapseExample");
      setCollapse(new Collapse(collapseElement));
    }
  });

  /* Same as before */
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <a
        className="btn btn-primary"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        href="#collapseExample"
        role="button"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-controls="collapseExample"
      >
        Link with href
      </a>
      <div className="collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <div className="card card-body">...</div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

I don't know if that's the right way to do it because I don't know much about React, but it works when I run it with `gatsby develop`.

When I build this project, I get the error. I understand that `document`, `window`, etc are not available in Node, but [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) it says the following:

> To fix this, find the offending code and either a) check before calling the code if window is defined so the code doesn’t run while Gatsby is building (see code sample below) or b) if the code is in the render function of a React.js component, **move that code into a componentDidMount lifecycle or into a useEffect hook**, which ensures the code doesn’t run unless it’s in the browser.

The code where I use `document.getElementById("collapseExample")` is inside the `useEffect`, so I'm not sure if I'm missing or misundertooding something because it keeps producing the same error when building.

The output of the building looks like this:

```
  852 |
  853 |
> 854 | EventHandler.on(document, EVENT_CLICK_DATA_API$7, SELECTOR_DISMISS, Alert.handleDismiss(new Alert()));
      | ^
  855 | /**
  856 |  * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  857 |  * jQuery


  WebpackError: ReferenceError: document is not defined
  
  - bootstrap.esm.js:854 
    [test-error]/[bootstrap]/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js:854:1
  
  - bootstrap:19 
    test-error/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
...
```

Can anyone tell me what is the correct way to use Bootstrap components with JavaScript and be able to build the project?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem with bootstrap 5. Replacing

```
import "bootstrap"
```

By

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following condition:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (collapse === null && typeof document !== "undefined") {
      const collapseElement = document.getElementById("collapseExample");
      setCollapse(new Collapse(collapseElement));
    }
  });
```

This is because, essentially, `gatsby build` occurs in the server-side where there's no [`window` or other global objects (such as `document`, because they are not even defined yet)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) while `gatsby develop` occurs in the client-side so you need to add the condition to avoid the triggering in the wrong side. That's why it works on `gatsby develop` but it doesn't in `gatsby build`.

> The code where I use `document.getElementById("collapseExample")` is
> inside the `useEffect`, so I'm not sure if I'm missing or
> misundertooding something because it keeps producing the same error
> when building.

Your `useEffect` has no dependencies (even an empty array, `[]`) so it's triggered on each side-effect of the state (initially for example), that's why it breaks your compilation.

Among adding the condition above, I would stronlgy recommend using React-based third-party dependencies (like [React-Boostsrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/)) to avoid this kind of troubles (potentially blocking [React's hydration](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/react-hydration/)).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I added the `typeof document !== "undefined"` condition, but I get the same error when building. I commented the line `setCollapse(new Collapse(collapseElement));` and it works, so I guess it means that `document` is defined when `document.getElementById("collapseExample");` is called, but I don't understand why it says `document` is undefined when calling `new Collapse()` in the next line.I wanted to use only Bootstrap cause it seemed more simple to control the style and behaviour of the components with JavaScript, but I think I'll try React-Bootstrap.

Comment: Try using the following condition: `(collapse === null && typeof window !== "undefined")`

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue while using bootstrap toasts. Though it is always better to use React-based libraries, but if you want to use plain Bootstrap, adding the below code to gatsby-node.js worked for me.

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
 if (stage === "build-html" || stage === "develop-html") {
   actions.setWebpackConfig({
     module: {
       rules: [
         {
           test: /bootstrap/,
           use: loaders.null(),
         },
       ],
     },
   });
  }
};
```

Here is the link to the gatsby debug blog I used: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/#fixing-third-party-modules